# How do I access $scope in chained $request promises?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-resource

I have a promise chain that looks like this ...

```
this.getFile(fileId).then(updateFile).then(displayAllDoneMessage);
```

where `getFile()` and `updateFile()` each use `ngResource` to construct the appropriate JSON call, and then return the `$resource.$promise`.

The chain fires OK, but I'm having a problem accessing `$scope` from within `updateFile`

So in `getFile()` I have

```
// this works
this.status.text = "fetching file"
```

But in `updateFile()` I have

```
// this fails at runtime because "this" is not $scope
this.status.text = "updating file"
```

What am I doing wrong, or what extra do I need to do to make `$scope` available within `updateFile()`?

I should possibly add that I'm using TypeScript in case that is significant.

Comment: are you using the "controller as" syntax?

Comment: I'm not, but that was one of the things I was going to try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `this.getFile`, the context is `this`, in your case, I guess `this` is the $scope object so `this` inside `getFile` is the $scope.

But `updateFile` and `displayAllDoneMessage` are invoked by the framework as a callback and `this` no longer refers to the $scope.

Try [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the $scope as the context:

```
this.getFile(fileId).then(updateFile.bind(this)).then(displayAllDoneMessage.bind(this));
```

For older browsers, you could include this script as a polyfill (quoted from the docs):

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        fToBind = this, 
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and proposed solution, and link to bind(). When I read the Mozilla docs, it suggests that bind is only supported on IE9 and above. Would that make this solution inappropriate for older browsers?

Comment: @pinoyyid: there is an implementation as a polyfill. You could include that script to make it work with older browsers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the extra time to add the polyfill.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using TypeScript and you want to maintain your `this` pointer, then you need to ensure you are using the lambda syntax.

Assuming you have saved off your `$scope` as a private/public variable in your constructor like this:

```
constructor(private $scope){ /* snip */ }
```

Then you can simply do this to ensure you are accessing your `$scope` like so:

```
this.getFile(fileid)
.then((result) => {
   return this.$scope.updateFile(result);
})
.then((result) => {
   return this.$scope.displayAllDoneMessage(result);
});
```

Under the hood this gets compiled down to something like the following:

```
//Save 'this' off to a closure
var _this = this;

_this.getFile(fileid)
.then(function(result){
   return _this.$scope.updateFile(result);
})
.then(function(result){
   return _this.$scope.displayAllDoneMessage(result);
});
```

TypeScipt uses a closure to maintain the appropriate references to `this`

Comment: Great answer. I've tested this and confirm it works. This will also help with scope issues throughout my code, so doubleplusgood. Upvoted! I've accepted the answer from @KhanhTO simply because syntactically it is cleaner which was one of my objectives for using promises in place of nested callbacks.